# 3D-plot of the error function in a linear regression

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot, machine-learning

I would like to visually plot a 3D graph of the error function calculated for a given slope and y-intercept for a linear regression.
This graph will be used to illustrate a gradient descent application.

Let’s suppose we want to model a set of points with a line. To do this we’ll use the standard y=mx+b line equation where m is the line’s slope and b is the line’s y-intercept. To find the best line for our data, we need to find the best set of slope m and y-intercept b values.

A standard approach to solving this type of problem is to define an error function (also called a cost function) that measures how “good” a given line is. This function will take in a (m,b) pair and return an error value based on how well the line fits the data. To compute this error for a given line, we’ll iterate through each (x,y) point in the data set and sum the square distances between each point’s y value and the candidate line’s y value (computed at mx+b). It’s conventional to square this distance to ensure that it is positive and to make our error function differentiable. In python, computing the error for a given line will look like:

```py
# y = mx + b
# m is slope, b is y-intercept
def computeErrorForLineGivenPoints(b, m, points):
    totalError = 0
    for i in range(0, len(points)):
        totalError += (points[i].y - (m * points[i].x + b)) ** 2
    return totalError / float(len(points))
```

Since the error function consists of two parameters (m and b) we can visualize it as a two-dimensional surface.

**Now my question, how can we plot such 3D-graph using python ?**

Here is a skeleton code to build a 3D plot.  This code snippet is totally out of the question context but it show the basics for building a 3D plot.
For my example i would need the x-axis being the slope, the y-axis being the y-intercept and the z-axis, the error.

Can someone help me build such example of graph ?

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def fun(x, y):
  return x**2 + y

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

The above code produce the following plot, which is very similar to what i am looking for.
[image: Here is what the above code produce]

Comment: @csgillespie no, i removed the R tag, I didn't noticed it was added; thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply replace `fun` with `computeErrorForLineGivenPoints`:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections

def error(m, b, points):
    totalError = 0
    for i in range(0, len(points)):
        totalError += (points[i].y - (m * points[i].x + b)) ** 2
    return totalError / float(len(points))

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

m, b = 3, 2
noise = np.random.random(x.size)
points = [Point(xp, m*xp+b+err) for xp,err in zip(x, noise)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ms = np.linspace(2.0, 4.0, 10)
bs = np.linspace(1.5, 2.5, 10)

M, B = np.meshgrid(ms, bs)
zs = np.array([error(mp, bp, points) 
               for mp, bp in zip(np.ravel(M), np.ravel(B))])
Z = zs.reshape(M.shape)

ax.plot_surface(M, B, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, color='b', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('m')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('error')

plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Tip: I renamed `computeErrorForLineGivenPoints` as `error`. Generally, there is no need to name a function `compute...` since almost all functions compute something. You also do not need to specify "GivenPoints" since the function signature shows that `points` is an argument. If you have other error functions or variables in your program, `line_error` or `total_error` might be a better name for this function.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu This is exactly the implementation I am looking for.  I will change the function signature as you suggest.  Thanks !