# Plot 3D error function depending on two variables

Tags: c, matlab, plot, octave

I'm looking to do something similar to this [3D-plot of the error function in a linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542686/3d-plot-of-the-error-function-in-a-linear-regression) but in octave.

I have a function `f(a,b)` that returns me an error `r` and two list of multiple values of `a` and `b` I want to run this function and evaluate the error. Since this is a multidimensional function is not enough for me to plot a 2d line plot to show the error but rather go with a 3d plot.

Given two list:

```
list_a =[.1 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000]
list_b =[.1 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000]
```

And the function `f(a,b)`, which is the most optimal way to create this 3d plot? Creating a `matrix_r` that represents the error for each combination and then plot it?

If I had that matrix, how can I plot it in 3d using octave?

Thanks

Comment: you want first a `meshgrid`, then evaluate the function on those points, then `surf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example. Given your choice of lists, I made it logarithmic :)

```matlab
list_a = logspace( -1, 5, 50 );
list_b = logspace( -1, 5, 50 );

f      = @ (a,b) (a+b).^2;   % a simulated  error function

[ Grid_a, Grid_b ] = ndgrid( list_a, list_b );

F = log( f( Grid_a, Grid_b ) );   % log error evaluated on the gridpoints

SurfObj = surf( list_a, list_b, F );

Axes = get( SurfObj, 'parent' );
set( Axes, 'xscale', 'log', 'yscale', 'log' )   % use logarithmic axes
```

From here you can also give it a custom colorbar, e.g.

```matlab
CBar   = colorbar;
toLog  = @(x) sprintf('10e%d', x);
CTicks = get( CBar, 'ytick' );
set( CBar, 'yticklabel', arrayfun( toLog, CTicks, 'UniformOutput', false ) )
```

[image]

Or if you prefer to focus on the shape rather than the values, you can create a solid coloured object and put lighting on it:

```matlab
set( SurfObj, 'facecolor', 'blue' )
light( 'position', [8, 12, 25] )
```

[image]

Comment: Nice cannon answer. One detail though, I would rename your `Axes` handle to `AxeObj` (to stay consistent with your `SurfObj`), or anything other than the current name. It is too close to the built in function `axes`. I know these calls are case sensitive but relying on a single letter case to differentiate between 2 very different types of objects is asking for trouble when the code grows ...