# Can we plot a correlation coefficient in 3D?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics, pearson-correlation

I'm currently going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542686/3d-plot-of-the-error-function-in-a-linear-regression) answer and attempting to establish a link between its contents and the application of plotting [Pearson coefficient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html). I'm wondering if it's possible to do so, and if someone could provide an example and clarification. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.